# I am trying to send mail through a java class then show error is->

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

When i send email through a java class then show error please tell me solution

com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException: 530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first. j9-20020aa78009000000b004fde2dd78b0sm9989611pfi.109 - gsmtp

```
BlManager bm = new BlManager();
Contactus cu = new Contactus();
String name, email,subject,msg;
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws 
ServletException,IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

    name = request.getParameter("name");
    email = request.getParameter("email");
    subject = request.getParameter("subject");
    msg = request.getParameter("message");

    final String username = "";// your email id
    final String password = "";// your password
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth","true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.STARTTLS.enable","true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");
    props.put("mail.smtp.ssl.protocols","TLSv1.2");

    Session session = Session.getInstance(props, new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
        @Override
        protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
            return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
        }
    });
    try {
        Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(username));
        String[] listofIDS = { username, email };
        for (String cc : listofIDS) {
            message.addRecipients(Message.RecipientType.CC, InternetAddress.parse(cc));
        }
        message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(email));
        MimeBodyPart textPart = new MimeBodyPart();
        Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();
        String final_Text = "Name: " + name + "" + "Email: " + email + "" + "Subject: "
                + subject + "" + "Mesaage: " + msg;
        textPart.setText(final_Text);
        message.setSubject(subject);
        multipart.addBodyPart(textPart);
        message.setContent(multipart);
        message.setSubject("Contact Details");
        Transport.send(message);
        cu.setName(name);
        cu.setEmail(email);
        cu.setSubject(subject);
        cu.setMessage(msg);
        bm.savecontactus(cu);
        out.println("<center><h2 style='color:green;'>Email Sent Successfully.</h2>");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        out.println(e);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Rather than `out.println(e);` use `e.printStackTrace();`

Comment: Also try `props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");`